# Can I use examples of others' research in my presentation on scientific conference?

Tags: conference, presentation, science

I'm giving a talk on scientific conference in a couple of days and I have prepared my concept and my presentation. Because what I'm going to talk about is not done in practise in my country, I have included in my presentation examples and research results from the past from other academics and researchers.

Is this okay? I will also give credits underneath each slide to the respected researchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to do that. If you do an introduction on the topic or you are comparing your results/methods to others you can talk about/show their work and you even should do that.

Just be careful that you talk enough about your own research and you always make it very clear if something was done by someone else.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, not only you *can* use others' research, but you *should*. It is important to highlight relationship of your research to prior knowledge.

If you only show what you have done (or are trying to do), then unless you are doing something simultaneously remarkably novel and easy to grasp at the same time (a dubious combination), you will, at best, come across as uninteresting and/or incomprehensible. Even more likely, it will look like you did no background research of your own, which makes you look incompetent.